# Dealing with Bubble Chart overlap

Tags: highcharts

We're working on a Highcharts Bubble Chart w/category axis and a lot of overlapping data points. Is there any way to control exactly how the bubbles are placed within the category? What we'd like to do is sort the bubbles ahead of time and then offset them from each other a bit. Some overlap is desirable so we'd prefer to not have to add additional categories to make sure there is no overlap.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately we have no solution for controling positions of the bubbles. But you can request your propositin in our uservoice system http://highcharts.uservoice.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using categories, your x values are the array index of the category for your value.

So to tweak the placement, you can tweak your x value by adding/subtracting small decimal amounts:

http://jsfiddle.net/yPLVP/10/

```
[-0.1,2,10]
```

Keeping in mind that +/- .5 is the center point between the categories - so for a value that falls within the 3rd category (x value 2), keep your x values between 1.55 and 2.45 (or so....)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, you can add this code:

```
function(chartObj) {
    $.each(chartObj.series[0].data, function(i, point) {
        var aux = 0;
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            aux = point.dataLabel.y + 6;
        else
            aux = point.dataLabel.y - 6;

        point.dataLabel.attr({y:aux});
    });
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9m6wu/277/